# Resolving Typescript module definition conflicts in dependencies

Tags: typescript, types, koa

I'm using two Koa middlewares in my Typescript project: `koa-joi-router` and `koa-bodyparser`. When I attempt to transpile the code, I get this error: `All declarations of 'body' must have identical modifiers.` When I checked the type definitions in the DefinitelyTyped repo, I found that they conflict.

I've tried creating a new module definition locally, but I get the same error.

```js
declare module "koa" {
    interface Request {
        body: any;
        rawBody: string;
    }
}
```

```js
declare module "koa" {
    interface Request {
        body?: any;
        params: {[key: string]: string};
    }
}
```

Is there any way to merge or override type definitions with conflicts?

Comment: I've had a bunch of issues with the koa ecosystem and typescript and started [curveballjs](https://github.com/curveballjs/core) as a koa-inspired pure TS framework. Might not be a solution for you though. If not, could you send a pull request to DefinitelyTyped to fix these issues?

Comment: Sent a pull request to DefinitelyTyped, but I feel like there must be a way to resolve these sorts of module conflicts, and if not there really should be.